# Draw a square based on chars in editor

Tags: c#, drawing, visual-studio-extensions

I want to draw a border outline of matching braces by clicking on one of them. Just like [ReSharpers Brace Matching option](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Matching_Delimiters.html).

The code itself kinda works but I want the border to be a simple square and I have absolutely no idea how to achieve that.

What it looks like now:

[image: way to complex border]

What I want:

[image]

Here's the Code. It's based on a Microsofts exmple vor Visual Studio Extentions for mark a specific char.

```
private void Draw(int from, int to)
{
    var fromTo = new List<int> { from, to }.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
    from = fromTo.First();
    to = fromTo.Last();

    var textViewLines = this.view.TextViewLines;

    var span = new SnapshotSpan(this.view.TextSnapshot, Span.FromBounds(from, to + 1));
    var geometry = (textViewLines as IWpfTextViewLineCollection).GetMarkerGeometry(span);
    if (geometry != null)
    {
        this.Draw(span, geometry);
    }
}

private void Draw(SnapshotSpan span, Geometry geometry)
{
    var drawing = new GeometryDrawing(new SolidColorBrush(), this.pen, geometry);
    drawing.Freeze();

    var drawingImage = new DrawingImage(drawing);
    drawingImage.Freeze();

    var image = new Image {
        Source = drawingImage
    };

    Canvas.SetLeft(image, geometry.Bounds.Left);
    Canvas.SetTop(image, geometry.Bounds.Top);

    this.layer.AddAdornment(AdornmentPositioningBehavior.TextRelative, span, null, image, null);
}
```

Comment: Seems to me that the Square box is drawn using the bounds at each line in your case, Whereas you need the Width of the box to be based on the longest line within the scope.